# How to aggregate a boolean column in Pandas Dataframe in a Pivot Table as percentage

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, boolean

I have a Pandas Dataframe. Among its many columns are ID, which is Boolean, Quarter, which gives year and quarter (e.g. 2016Q1) and State (e.g. TX, CA), so it would look something like:

```
id    Quarter State
True  15Q1    AZ
False 17Q1    WY
True  14Q2    NH
False 15Q1    AZ
```

I'm trying to build a pivot table with ID as the value, State as the index, and quarter as the columns. I'd like to use `np.mean` as the `agg_func` but I get `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

It displays right when I use `count` as the aggregate function instead. And when I aggregate the total `np.mean(df['id'])`, I get `.64`, which is exactly the type of output I'm looking for except more aggregated instead of granular. So why does `np.sum` work there, but not when I use it as the aggregating function in a pivot table? How do I get it to work.

I think I could convert the `True`'s and `False`'s to 1's and 0's, but I'd prefer not to, since I actually have a lot of 'id' columns I'm looking to aggregate this way.

EDIT: So it's an issue that only pops up with my full dataset, and not the toy dataset I used as an example. I played around some more and the `ValueError: No objects to concatenate` still pops up if I do a groupby with mean as the aggregating function on 'Year' or 'State'. It even pops up when I try `df['id'].describe()`

Has anyone ever encountered an issue like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Your output is not very clear but this is what I think you need

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='State', columns='Quarter', values = 'id', aggfunc='mean')
```

You get

```
Quarter 14Q2    15Q1    17Q1
State           
AZ      NaN     0.5     NaN
NH      1.0     NaN     NaN
WY      NaN     NaN     0.0
```

You can pass the parameter fill_values = 0 in pivot_table to replace the NaNs by 0

Comment: Hmmm, that's what I tried and it didn't work. I think my actual dataset has something weird that the toy dataset doesn't. I'll dig into it further, but I doubt I can get everything into the question. Thanks for your help, though.